# Does Indexing rank-feature values in Elasticsearch cause a full update cycle?

Tags: elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rank-feature.html is a really cool way to quickly assist scoring results with values known at index time, but what if I need to update those values in the index a lot? Do rank-feature and rank-features cause a full update to a document (delete the whole document and then re-index it) when I update them?

Apologies if I messed anything up, I am new here! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents in Elasticsearch (Lucene) are immutable. So any time you update a field, it will require a full re-index of the document. The field type shouldn't make a difference here.